# Fill a form with WatiN in C#

Tags: c#, forms, watin

that's my first question, i hope i'm doing everything correctly. 
Anyway, i have a weird issue. I basically have this HTML input which i want to fill with WatiN :

```
<input name="edit[id]" class="form-text required" id="edit-id" type="text" size="60" maxlength="64" value="">
```

That's my code in C# :

```
IE ie = new IE();
ie.GoTo(urlhere, just too long);
ie.TextField(Find.ByName("edit[id]")).TypeText("Text");
```

It's not working and it returns this exception :

> Ulteriori informazioni: Could not find INPUT (hidden) or INPUT (password) or INPUT (text) or INPUT (textarea) or TEXTAREA element tag matching criteria: Attribute 'name' equals 'edit[id]' at about:blank

I'm not sure why it gives "at about:blank" honestly. I tried with a random google page and the code it's working. If i put a random name instead of the correct one, it gives me the same exception but with the correct url instead of "about:blank".
Note : I'm trying to fill a form. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please do not post error messages as screenshots. Put the actual text in your question, it's more convenient to see and can then be indexed for searching.

Comment: Done, thank for your suggestion!

Comment: perhaps you have multiple tabs open? where one of those tabs is a blank page? A blank page is named about:blank

Comment: Yeah i know but no, i only have one page which is the one opened by the "ie.GoTo".

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what web page are you using but from the information you posted it looks like that form might be "somewhere else" (another div, frame, etc.) To be able to find the EXACT entry you should press F12 (IE) or CTRL+SHIFT+I (Chrome) and traverse the HTML web page to find the exact portion were the input lies and you will find the exact spot.

The code you posted is perfectly fine, there's nothing else you need to do to make it work. If you need more help, posting the webpage you are trying to use will go a long way (if possible, of course).